# Can’t create an environment (Conda or pipenv) that works properly with Jupyter

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda, jupyter-lab

### **The long-short:**

One day in July, noticed that Jupyter wasn’t importing the version of Seaborn I installed to my Conda env. It was downloading an older Seaborn from a global dir. Same for all other packages when I checked versions. After various attempts at fixing this, Jupyter doesn’t even import packages now. I’ve tried with pipenv too. In both Conda and pipenv, sys.path reveals more path variables than I know what to do with, sometimes including the desired env path, sometimes not. But either way Jupyter imports are ignoring the env path I want to use, instead looking for global packages that I have deleted since July in attempt to solve the issue. On top of this (but probably intertwined in a way I just don’t understand yet), I’m not getting kernels that connect Jupyter to the desired env directories where packages are installed. Global python gets used instead of the env’s python instance. Not sure exactly how kernels are created, but I can tell that they are either not being created for some new envs, not accessing env-specific python & packages, or failing to connect (loads a stale kernel.json file and fails to start.)

### **Desired outcome:**

***How do I get JupyterLab to import the intended package version from the intended env directories? Even deeper, How do I get environments back to their former functionality of automatically [1] creating their own python instance, [2] creating  their own kernel recognized by Jupyter, [3] creating  their own path to the env, and [4] initializing all of that in Jupyter Lab?***

### **Things I have tried:**

- Deactivated the base env, which admittedly I wasn’t doing for the first few weeks of July until I remembered that is a must for Windows Conda… but still now that I’m regularly deactivating base, why would these issues still persist?
- Uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled Miniconda
- Deleted (I believe) all stray / older pythons from my machine, reinstalled a fresh user-level Python 3.9
- Verified that packages are installing with the `conda list` command. They just won’t import properly in JupyterLab
- Some tweaks to Path variables in Windows settings, but was very cautious and have no idea how to / if I am revising those properly. Clearly not though seeing as the issue is still alive 3 months later 0.o  No idea if I should be editing user variables or system variables, or how to trim the paths cautiously.
- Reinstalled jupyter and jupyterlab
- Reinstalled ipykernel
- Noted that `sys.executable`, `sys.path`, and `!where python` give different outputs in shell python versus Jupyter Lab python
- Switching kernels manually in JupyterLab (usually the manually selected kernel is DOA)
- Tried manually rewriting `sys.path` in notebook.
- Tried launching JupyterLab from a fresh pipenv instead of Miniconda
- Got a pipenv working correctly for a Streamlit applet in August, using raw python in VS Code (This may isolate the issue to Jupyter? I had to continue the other Jupyter-based project in Google collab since JupyterLab started choking in July.)

### **Deeper details:**

Sheesh this post is already getting long… but here I’ve picked out the 4 most prominent code / error snippets. There are more where that came from, but hopefully there might be something in here that you might recognize as the needle in the haystack.

### [1]

When the `kernel-session.json` causes a stillborn kernel, it is created as a totally blank json file. Running `jupyter lab` in the conda terminal yields this error message, buried in the output:

```
    Failed to load connection file:
'C:\\Users\\David.000\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-a6082e80-0b65-48f1-b370-7c2918030185.json'
```

I’ve found past `kernel-session.json` files that were not stillborn, such as this one called `kernel-b146b600-81e3-418e-a55f-5a3fbbc13471.json`, which looks like this, auto-populated:

```
{
  "shell_port": 50877,
  "iopub_port": 50878,
  "stdin_port": 50879,
  "control_port": 50880,
  "hb_port": 50881,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "caa915a4-00a599e8b6c4db6417bcca77",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

### [2]

`sys.executable`, when run in shell python, yields the proper python location within the env:

```
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\python.exe'
```

But `sys.executable`, when run in Jupyter Lab, is latching onto the global Python:

```
sys.executable
'C:\\Python39\\python.exe'
```

### [3]

`sys.path`, when run in shell python, seems to yield the env specific paths I want (though why are there so many??)

```
    >>> sys.path
        ['', 'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\python39.zip',
'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\David.000\\miniconda3\\envs\\aucu_ml\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

But `sys.path`, when run in Jupyter Lab, is also showing a butt-load of paths, many of which are unwanted globals:

```
sys.path
[> ['C:\\Users\\David.000\\Desktop\\Civic Innovation Corps\\Miami\\Predictive_Analytics_Business_Licensing',
'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip',
'C:\\Python39\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python39\\lib',
'C:\\Python39',
'',
'C:\\Users\\David.000\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\David.000\\.ipython']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not well-defined behavior when other site-packages leak into Conda environments via PYTHONPATH or by having user- or system-level Python installations. When Conda is the only source of Python, everything is quite easy to think about. Otherwise, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks @merv. So should I be seeking to manipulate PYTHONPATH to resolve this? Would that generalize to future environments? How would I go about making conda the only source of Python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not qualified to answer this but what the heck.

I have several kernels associated with different environments that are configured to run different programs. I created them in the terminal and I make it a practice to install any module/program etc, within the terminal in the activated environment that I need it in instead of installing within the notebook.

If I'm using a desktop, then before opening Juypter I select the appropriate environment within anaconda. If I'm using a virtual machine then within the terminal I activate the environment and once I'm in the notebook, select the appropriate kernel.

While I can't be sure, I think your problem is occurring because of how/where you're installing or updating packages.

Comment: Thank you @newbzzs. To clarify the steps of how my env creation went, I (1st) listed the packages I knew I would need on a requirements.txt, then (2nd) had conda create the env from the requirements.txt. I would (3rd) enter the env in terminal, (4th) and open JupyterLab from there. I assumed kernels pointing to the env's python were created automatically by following that flow. Is that not the case? Do I need to reconfig a setting to make that happen? At one point (I think after I reinstalled ipykernel) I did create a kernel for the env in shell. That kernel is the one that acts stillborn.